# Why does std::sort appears to alternate the values in the vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl

The below code snippet shows that std::sort is alternating the values in the vector which is quite confusing.

```
std::vector<int> a;
std::vector<std::string> b;
std::vector<std::pair<int&, std::string&>> p;

a.push_back(1);
a.push_back(3);
a.push_back(2);
b.push_back("hi 1");
b.push_back("hi 3");
b.push_back("hi 2");

p.push_back(std::pair<int&, std::string&>(a[0],b[0]));
p.push_back(std::pair<int&, std::string&>(a[1],b[1]));
p.push_back(std::pair<int&, std::string&>(a[2],b[2]));

std::sort(p.begin(),p.end());

std::cout << a[0] << " " << a[1] << " " << a[2] <<  std::endl;
std::cout << b[0] << " " << b[1] << " " << b[2] <<  std::endl;
```

I am expecting it to print

```
1 2 3
hi 1 hi 2 hi 3
```

but instead it prints

```
1 3 3
hi 1 hi 3 hi 3
```

Why? My compiler is gcc 4.9.3.

I am trying to sort two vectors together and using vector of pairs of references is suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/37929675/3667089.

Comment: You are only sorting `p`, not `a` and `b`. Also, using `std::sort` with `std::pair`s sorts lexicographically - this might not be what you want, if instead you want to sort based on the `first` field then use a lambda in `std::sort` (not the downvoter btw).

Comment: @ArchbishopOfBanterbury but `p` has references to `a` and `b`, shouldn't alternating `p` automatically update `a` and `b`?

Comment: Also look for std:stable_sort - if two values are evaluated to the same amount, normal sort can alternate them as it wishes as it does not have to use a stable sort.

Comment: Looks like you have a dangling reference.

Comment: Since all the `first` values here are distinct, lexicographical order is the same as sorting by`first`, and there's no need for a stable sort.

Comment: @uh Where? The things referenced all have a lifetime longer than the references.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan `std:stable_sort` returns 2 2 3. Even more confusing.

Comment: My point is for after you fix the major bugs others have found...

Comment: Looks like a bug in `libstdc++`; clang with `libc++` works as expected.

Comment: I don't think this is a bug; I think there is a mismatch of expectations on the behavior of *values* of a type containing *references*.

Comment: Here is [Visual C++ 2015's output](http://rextester.com/GBOMC67308)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the insertion sort implementation. Since there are less number of elements, sort decides to perform an insertion sort.

Problematic code:

```
template<typename _RandomAccessIterator>
    void
    __unguarded_linear_insert(_RandomAccessIterator __last)
    {
      typename iterator_traits<_RandomAccessIterator>::value_type
        __val = _GLIBCXX_MOVE(*__last);
      _RandomAccessIterator __next = __last;
      --__next;
      while (__val < *__next)
        {
          *__last = _GLIBCXX_MOVE(*__next); <<< PROBLEMATIC Code
          __last = __next;
          --__next;
        }
      *__last = _GLIBCXX_MOVE(__val);
    }
```

Now it goes inside the while loop for the index 2 and index 3 case. Before going into the while loop, `__val` has the value `2 and hi 2`. But after doing the first `move` inside the while, `__val` also changes to `3 and hi 3` and outside the while `last` is set to `3 and hi 3`, which is incorrect.

**UPDATE: libc++**
Code in libc++ for this is pretty straightforward and boils down to comparing just 3 values in `__sort3`. libc++ uses `swap` instead of `move` unlike `libstd++` and hence works.

So, seems like moving on reference types is not good as it overwrites the data when the `moved` element is assigned with new value. <strike>Perhaps the same would be the result in libc++ also if we use more than 3 or 4 elements in which case it will also use `move` under a generic insertion sort routine.</strike>

**UPDATE 2:**
Checking more into it, libc++ always uses `swap` at least for insertion_sort, so no trouble there.

To quote from standard on why references are not good to be stored in container:
(Section 23.2)

> Containers are objects that store other objects. They control
>   allocation and deallocation of these objects through constructors,
>   destructors, insert and erase operations.

And the table beneath that has this requirement:

> X::value_type - T Requires: T is compile time type Destructible

Though I am not sure if `reference type` is destructible or not. If not, we should better get compile time errors for storing references in STL containers.

Comment: This seems to indicate that sort only works for vector of values. I wonder why sorting vector of references even compiles... do you think this is a bug in libstdc++?

Comment: @user3667089 See my updated answer for libc++. I do not think its a bug in compiler. I believe its just bad to hold references in container. I am not sure how it would be with `std::refernce_wrapper`.

Comment: Agree there should be compile time errors for storing references in STL containers. Using vector of pairs of references doesn't seem like the right way. Back to the original problem, given vector `a`and `b`, is there anyway to apply `std::sort` to sort both vectors based on the values in `a` without a copy overhead?

Comment: Well, there is something fundamentally wrong if you are trying to sort one container and expecting another container to be sorted as well. What you can do is, store the iterators of `a` and `b` as  a pair in `p` and provide your custom comparator to the sort, which would be something similar to what pair does, only difference being you will have to dereference the iterator. Once `p` is sorted, you can iterate through it as if sorted `a` or `b`.

Answer (score 2):

I would say `std::pair<int&, std::string&>` is not swappable. `std::swap` seems to work though, but if you think in a naive swap, it won't work with references

```
std::pair<int&, std::string&> pair0(a[0],b[0]);
std::pair<int&, std::string&> pair1(a[1],b[1]);

std::pair<int&, std::string&> tmp(pair0);
pair0 = pair1;
pair1 = tmp;
```

then `pair0` gets overwritten by `pair1`.

References in general won't work with STL containers.

Comment: `ValueSwappable` is only for iterators.

Comment: @Hurkyl, true, the pair is just not swappable (I suppose) then the iterators in the vector of pairs are not ValueSwappable

Comment: I ran your code but `a` and `b` still remains the same and only `p` got sorted. If there is going to be an extra step needed to copy the values from `p` back to `a` and `b`, why not just pass by value to `p` at the first place?

Comment: ooops true, in this situation `reference_wrapper` is no better than a pointer, I'll remove the code since it doesn't solve your problem

Comment: So using vector of pairs of references doesn't seem like the right way. Back to the original problem, given vector `a` and `b`, is there anyway to apply `std::sort` to sort both vectors based on the values in `a` without a copy overhead?

Comment: @user3667089: That probably deserves to be asked as an independent question.

Comment: I cannot come up with any way of doing that, you could always implement your own sort function but I wouldn't unless really necessary. I would reconsider though whether you need to do this in the first place, can't you use a `map` instead of two vectors?

Answer (score 1):

It's possibly a bug in libstdc++. I added a "debug" comparator to see the sort in action for both libstdc++ and libc++:

```
std::sort(p.begin(), p.end(), [&] (const auto& ap, const auto& bp)
{
    std::cout << "Debug: " << ap.first << " " << bp.first << " | ";
    for (auto e : a)
        std::cout << e << " ";
    std::cout << " | ";
    for (auto e : b)
        std::cout << e << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";
    return ap.first < bp.first;
});
```

And this is the output:

```
Debug: 1 1 | 1 3 2  | hi 1 hi 3 hi 2 
Debug: 3 1 | 1 3 2  | hi 1 hi 3 hi 2 
Debug: 3 1 | 1 3 2  | hi 1 hi 3 hi 2 
Debug: 2 1 | 1 3 2  | hi 1 hi 3 hi 2 
Debug: 2 3 | 1 3 2  | hi 1 hi 3 hi 2 
Debug: 3 1 | 1 3 3  | hi 1 hi 3 hi 3 
1 3 3
hi 1 hi 3 hi 3
--------------------------
Debug: 3 1 | 1 3 2  | hi 1 hi 3 hi 2 
Debug: 2 3 | 1 3 2  | hi 1 hi 3 hi 2 
Debug: 2 1 | 1 2 3  | hi 1 hi 2 hi 3 
1 2 3
hi 1 hi 2 hi 3
```

For some reason the `2` element gets overwritten by a `3`.

The other possibility is that `std::pair<int&, std::string&>` does not meet the definition of [`ValueSwappable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/ValueSwappable). That is, when the actual swapping of elements occur in the sort function, you are experiencing undefined behavior.

Comment: `std::swap(p[0],p[1])` works fine so it is for sure ValueSwappable. I am so surprised that this is because of a bug in libstdc++... if no one else follows up with new answers I will accept your answer

Comment: @user3667089: No, `std::swap` _compiles_, but I don't think it has sane behavior, and I doubt it fulfills ValueSwappable.

Comment: `ValueSwappable` is only for iterators.